# React and rSocket REQUEST_CHANNEL error with Spring Boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-gemfire, rsocket

We have a working demo between React and Spring Boot Data Geode using rSocket for fire & forget, request response and request stream but when we try and use request channel we get error:

`org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Destination 'quotes' does not support REQUEST_CHANNEL. Supported interaction(s): [REQUEST_STREAM]`

So far on web it looks like this ought to be possible from [RSocket Git](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket-js/issues/52)

It's a simple spring boot app with @Controller endpoints that run over rSocket like this:

```
@Controller
public class RSocketController {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger(RSocketController.class);

    @Autowired
    PriceService priceService;

    @MessageMapping(value = "quotes")
    public Flux<Quote> getQuotes() {
        log.info("In getQuotes");

        return priceService.generatePrices();
    }  
}
```

The `generatePrices` returns a Flux of prices which works fine in request stream but we would prefer to use request channel for bi-directional comms.

**Client versions**

```
"rsocket-core": "0.0.19"
"rsocket-flowable": "0.0.14"
"rsocket-tcp-client": "0.0.19"
"rsocket-websocket-client": "0.0.19"
```

**Client code**

```
const transport = new RSocketWebSocketClient(transportOptions);
const rSocketClient = new RSocketClient({serializers, setup, transport});
​
rSocketClient.connect().subscribe({
    onComplete: socket => {
        console.log('Client connected to the RSocket Server');
​
        socket.requestChannel(Flowable.just({
            data: 'foyss',
            metadata: String.fromCharCode(6) + 'quotes'
        })).subscribe({
            onComplete: function() {
                console.log(`Channel received end of server stream`);
            },
            onError: function(err) {
                console.log("err", err);
            },
            onNext: payload => {
                console.log(payload);
            },                
            onSubscribe: function(subscription) {
                console.log("got subscription");
                subscription.request(0x7fffffff);
            },
            onError: error => {
                console.log(error);
            },
            onSubscribe: cancel => {
                console.log('onSubscribe cancel');
            }})
        },
        onError: error => {
            console.log(error);
        },
        onSubscribe: cancel => {
            // console.log(cancel);
            console.log('onSubscribe cancel');
        }
})
```

Comment: Could you post the client code. Also, Which version of rsocket-js client are you using?

Comment: Would appreciate any help on this matter :)

Comment: @foyss yes I was able to replicate same issue you are having but not sure why it is not working. Probably need assistance of some one from spring rsocket project yo chime in.

Comment: I've had a look at the docs and for the js library, it's not yet implemented (apparently)

Comment: To support channel the method has to accept a flux of data as an argument. In your example you have created a stream (client send one request and server returns a stream of data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some JS libraries still don't support the request-channel model. Please check the official documentation for your JS lib, eg, for: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-rsocket-rxjs

```
Missing:
Lease Handling
Server Setup
Resume Support
Request Channel
.....
```